# How to move sub-tags to right after a mother tag?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an html in which there are many elements `<div class="ex_example"> .. </div>` inside `<div class="c-s">`, which is in turn inside `<div class="c-w"`, i.e.

```
<div class="c-w"
  <div class="c-s">
     <div class="ex_example"> .. </div>
     <div class="ex_example"> .. </div>
     <div class="ex_example"> .. </div>
</div></div>
```

Could you please elaborate in how to move all the `<div class="ex_example"> .. </div>` to right before `<div class="c-w"`. I mean

```
<div class="ex_example"> .. </div>
<div class="ex_example"> .. </div>
<div class="ex_example"> .. </div>
<div class="c-w"
  <div class="c-s">
</div></div>
```

My code is

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get('https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/aimer', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

Thank you so much for your help!

---

Update: I have the situation in which there are more than one `<div class="c-w"` and it's possible that some of them do not contain `<div class="c-s">`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="audio">link</div>

<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <div class="ex_example"> xx </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> yy </div>
  </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: I don't quite understand: do you want only to remove whitespaces to the left of `<div class="ex_example">` tags? For what purpose?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I'm sorry for my bad communication. Honestly, it's quite hard for me to find the correct jargon to express my intention. I meant I would like to have all `<div class="ex_example"> .. </div>`  being the same level but stand above `<div class="c-w"`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Because the content of `<div class="c-w"` is automatically hidden, so I move the content out and thus this display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question well: You can use `.insert_before()` to insert tags/strings before some tag/string:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
     <div class="ex_example"> 1.. </div>
     <div class="ex_example"> 2.. </div>
     <div class="ex_example"> 3.. </div>
</div></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for c in list(soup.select_one('div.c-s').contents):
    soup.select_one('div.c-w').insert_before(c)

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<div class="ex_example"> 1.. </div>
<div class="ex_example"> 2.. </div>
<div class="ex_example"> 3.. </div>
<div class="c-w">
<div class="c-s"></div></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've just encounter a situation in which there are more than one `<div class="c-w"` and it's possible that some of them do not contain `<div class="c-s">`. Could you please elaborate on how to modify your original code for this sitation?

Comment: @LAD I suggest to open a new question here on SO. Notify me then and I'll look at it.

Comment: Please see my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402127/how-to-move-sub-tags-to-right-after-a-mother-tag-in-case-there-are-more-than-1-o.