# How to move sub-tags to right after a mother tag in case there are more than 1 occurrence?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to move all sub-tags of each `<div class="c-s">` to right before the its mother tag `<div class="c-w">`. For example,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="audio">link</div>

<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <div class="ex_example"> xx </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> yy </div>
  </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
```

My expected output is the following BeautifulSoup object

```
<div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
<div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
<div class="ex_example"> cc </div>
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s"></div>
</div>
<div class="ex_example"> xx </div>
<div class="ex_example"> yy </div>
<div class="ex_example"> zz </div>
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s"></div>
</div>
```

This means the level of such `<div class="ex_example"> cc </div>` is the same as `<div class="c-w">`.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script will move all tags with `class="ex_example"` in front of parent `<div class="c-w">`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> cc </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="audio">link</div>

<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <div class="ex_example"> xx </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> yy </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> zz </div>
  </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for c_s in soup.select('div.c-s'):
    for c in list(c_s.contents):
        c.find_parent('div', class_='c-w').insert_before(c)

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
<div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
<div class="ex_example"> cc </div>
<div class="c-w">
<div class="c-s"></div>
</div>
<div class="audio">link</div>

<div class="ex_example"> xx </div>
<div class="ex_example"> yy </div>
<div class="ex_example"> zz </div>
<div class="c-w">
<div class="c-s"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As always, you code is elegant. IMHO, `.insert_before` **inserts** tags or strings immediately before something else in the parse tree. Could you please explain how it **moves** things in this case.

Comment: @LAD In the script, variable `c` can be of type `Tag`. Each `Tag` has it's parent. So `.insert_berore()` changes this `.parent` property to new parent - effectively moving the tag inside the HTML document tree (Note: `.contents` of the tag's parent is also changed with this action). There's also `.insert()` and `.insert_after()` methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Without you, my project can hardly be done.

Comment: Honestly, I'm very surprised by your knowledge.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you again. Could you please have a look at strange phenomenon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538180/why-does-this-extraction-work-fine-on-example-but-not-on-real-url)?