# Why does this extraction work fine on example, but not on real url?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the content of `href` in class `a`, which is inside `<td class="DataZone">`. It works in below example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<td class="DataZone"><div id="Content_CA_DI_0_DataZone">
<div style="font:bold 8pt 'Courier New';letter-spacing:-1px">
<a href="Browse-A">A</a> <a href="Browse-B">B</a> <a href="Browse-C">C</a> <a href="Browse-D">D</a> 
</div>
</div></td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

[tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('td.DataZone a')]
```

, and the result is `['Browse-A', 'Browse-B', 'Browse-C', 'Browse-D']`. When I apply it on real [url](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/), it unfortunately does not work

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get(url, headers = headers) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

[tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('td.DataZone a')]
```

It returns an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0a06dde2d97b> in <module>
      4 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
      5 
----> 6 [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('td.DataZone a')]

<ipython-input-12-0a06dde2d97b> in <listcomp>(.0)
      4 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
      5 
----> 6 [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('td.DataZone a')]

KeyError: 'href'
```

Clearly, the source of url is similar to the example

[image]

Could you please explain why such error occurs?

---

**Update:** It's weird for me that `[x['href'] for x in soup.select('td.DataZone a[href^=Browse]')]` works fine, but not `[x['href'] for x in soup.select('td.DataZone a')]`. Please elaborate on the issue too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error, because there's many `td.Datazone` tags, and inside one of the tag there's `<a>Google+</a>` - which is without `href`.

You can select by `td.DataZone a[href]` to select only `<a>` tags with `href` attribute:

```
print( [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('td.DataZone a[href]')] )
```

Comment: Your answer makes everything clear. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The point here that you are using a wrong `CSS` selector.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = [x['href'] for x in soup.select("a[href^=Browse]")]
    print(target)


main("https://www.thefreedictionary.com/")
```

Or:

```
target = [x for x in soup.select("td.DataZone a[href^=Browse]")]
```

Output:

```
['Browse-A', 'Browse-B', 'Browse-C', 'Browse-D', 'Browse-E', 'Browse-F', 'Browse-G', 'Browse-H', 'Browse-I', 'Browse-J', 'Browse-K', 'Browse-L', 'Browse-M', 'Browse-N', 'Browse-O', 'Browse-P', 'Browse-Q', 'Browse-R', 'Browse-S', 'Browse-T', 'Browse-U', 'Browse-V', 'Browse-W', 'Browse-X', 'Browse-Y', 'Browse-Z']
```

Update Based on User requirements in comment:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.select("td.DataZone"):
        for x in item.findAll(href=True):
            print(x['href'])


main("https://www.thefreedictionary.com/")
```

Comment: Could you please explain how I use a wrong `CSS` selector?

Comment: @LAD Indeed, according to your [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3XfQ.png) so the desired data is available withing `anchor` >> `a` where it's holding `href` starting with **Browse**

Comment: I don't get it. I thought that `Browse-A` is the value of `href`. I intend to take all the value of `href`, even it does not contain `Browse`. I mean what if there are some of `a` whose `href` does not contain `Browse`.

Comment: @LAD so your question is to getting `anchor` **href** values whenever it's under `td.DataZone` ?

Comment: Yeap, that's exactly what I want :)))

Comment: I don't know why `a[href^=Browse]` works, but not `a`.

Comment: @LAD here we are saying find all `anchor` tags where **href** starts with **Browse**

Comment: I'm so sorry, I can only upvote your answer. Honestly, @Andrej Kesely's answer clears my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like not all `<a>` tag has `href` attribute. Try this instead.

```py
l = [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('td.DataZone a') if 'href' in tag.attrs]
print(*l, sep = '\n')
```

You can also do this.

```py
l = [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('td.DataZone a[attr="href"]')]
print(*l, sep = '\n')
```

Comment: I've just checked and confirmed that all `<a>` has `href` attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry for my previous sloppy comment. You are right.